# Can we run stpm2 in Stata 15.1?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have tried to run a flexible parametric survival model using stpm2 in Stata 15.1, and I'm getting an error code of '3499 stpm2_setup() not found'. How we can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you check whether `stpm2` has been successfully installed using `ado dir`? It sounds like it hasn't been correctly installed. Maybe uninstall and reinstall from SSC.

Comment: I am working on a network computer, I will try to get it re-installed by the system administrator . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you type `viewsource stpm2.ado` and scroll down to the syntax definition, it says `version 11.1`, so you should be good with Stata 15.1. My version is 1.7.4 20Apr2020.

I would recommend reinstalling and typing `which stpm2` to make sure everything looks OK.

Comment: 'which stpm2' gives version 1.7.4 20 Apr2020. I will try to get it, reinstalled. Thanks !

Comment: I think that error means the function was not already loaded, it is not in
the libraries, and there is no .mo file with its name. If reinstall does not fix, maybe e-mail the author. There was [a thread on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1327076-stpm2-command-and-r-3499-error-message) where a reinstall fixed the problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I tried to install 'stpm2' in Stata14 and it works well. But some packages stpm2cr only works on Stata15. As you mentioned I will try to reinstall 'stpm2' package in Stata15.